# Unknown type for NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN and FOUNDATION_EXPORT

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am currently working on an old source code of objective C, I am using Xcode11 and set the base target as iOS10.

Project is running fine but when I am trying to build it I am getting these errors:-

Unknown type for NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN and FOUNDATION_EXPORT.

I tried importing Foundation in pch file but still same error.

Can anyone help me out on this.

Update: framework compiler flag settings
[image]
[image]

Here is project's pch file
[image]
[image]

Thanks

Comment: try adding prefix header path

Comment: I already tried this

Comment: In compiler settings check what custom compiler flags you have. I think if you add ```-fno-sanitize=returns-nonnull-attribute``` it may fix it, otherwise post those flags here as well. Also check your linker flags - what does it use for ```-framework```

Comment: I just updated my question @skaak

Comment: Hi - I have one of those, iOS 10 project in latest Xcode 11. No problems! I've tried to generate your error by removing e.g. Foundation (I think you need a ```-framework Foundation``` added to your framework settings) but even if I remove it it still compiles no problem. Also, I tried changing the version of the compiler and a few other things but I can not get your error. If it helps, set the iOS deployment target to 10 (which I assume you did) and maybe add Foundation to your frameworks. I really suspect the compiler and/or build settings but unless you somehow broke it, it should just work.

Comment: @skaak thanks buddy for your efforts, I already set the target to iOS10, please check update question about the pch file setting

Comment: @Mayank !! Tx, in my project I have different settings. I'll paste the image as an answer ...

Comment: @skaak I tried your suggested setting also but same error

Comment: @MayankJain Is the issue resolved?

Answer (score 2):

FWIW in my project I have Precompile Prefix Header set to no as in the image.

Other settings that may help - in 'Other Linker Flags' I also have

```
-framework "Foundation"
```

I hope you can get it right, here are two more things to try.

1. Force it by adding

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT=extern NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN= NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END=
```

to your preprocessor macros.

2. Since Foundation is included in the project and given that it is so old, maybe there are places (source files) where you need to add

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

to a header file to get it to work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks buddy for your help, I will try this out now. Are you available to have a quick Skype call. Actually I am stuck here from last 2 days. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After spending around 2 days, I found that there was nothing wrong in my source code or build setting, it was due to the disk space on my Mac.
If you are also facing this issue, you can try below things

1. Check the available disk space, or try building another project, make some room for project to build by cleaning up some space. I clear space with clean my Mac https://macpaw.com/cleanmymac
2. If you have pch file, cross check you if include foundation and UIKit framework and also check for pch prefix header path in build setting.This link may help
   https://useyourloaf.com/blog/modules-and-precompiled-headers/
3. Check your project target, foundation framework should be added there.

Hope these steps help you.